# maximum length of each numbers between zeros

Tags: r

I have a big matrix and I would like to find out, each rows maximum length of between zeros. 
small example

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    0   15   20   17    0    0    4    5
[2,]    0    7    0    8   20   18    0    1
[3,]    0    0    5    8    0    5    7    0
```

- first row has 2 group of numbers between zeros first one has 3 numbers and second one has 2, max length is 3 which is what I am looking for
- second row has 3 group between zeros and first one has 1 numbers, second one has 3 and third one has 1 number  max length is 3 number
- third row has 2 group between zeros first one and second one has 2 numbers clearly max length is 2.

I just want these max length numbers in the new matrix 
I hope its clear to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic base R approach using `apply` and `rle` where we return the maximum number of non-zero value between two zeroes.

```
apply(mat == 0, 1, function(x) {
    ind = rle(x)
    max(ind$lengths[!ind$values])
})

#[1] 3 3 2
```

---

Another approach which is more concise using `table` and `cumsum`

```
apply(mat == 0, 1, function(x) max(table(cumsum(x))) - 1)

#[1] 3 3 2
```

Comment: I am getting Error in apply(mat == 0, 1, function(R1) { : object 'mat' not found, why do you think?

Comment: @sametgok `mat` is your matrix object.

Comment: thank you very much, second approach worked perfectly.

Comment: can you also help me to find min length of zeros?

Comment: @sametgok minimum number of consecutive zeros for each row?

Comment: One-way is the `rle` way : `apply(mat == 0, 1, function(x) {
  ind = rle(x);
  max(ind$lengths[ind$values])
  })
`

Comment: I changed into max to min to get my result it worked, I am actually looking for min length between group of numbers in the row. to make it clear, if there is a more than two group of numbers I would like to know what is the min length of zeros in the each row. Thank you so much