# intensity of maximum length between zeros

Tags: r

[maximum length of each numbers between zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534117/maximum-length-of-each-numbers-between-zeros/48534194?noredirect=1#comment84064219_48534194) I have another question related to the link, 
in this question I would like to find out maximum intensity of maximum length of a group between zeros
for instance

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    0   15   20   17    0    0    4    5
[2,]    0    7    0    8   20   18    0    1
[3,]    0    0    5    8    0    5    7    0
```

from this small matrix in the first row I have two groups in between zeros one 15 20 17 which has 3 numbers that has the maximum  length in that row. intensity of maximum length is 52 (15+20+17). 
--same with the second row there are 3 groups between zeros and max length is 3 and intensity is 46(8+20+18).
-- in the third row there are two groups between zeros 5 8 and 5 7 and i would like to find out two of these groups intensity 13 and 12. 
I hope you did not confuse.thanks

Comment: So what code have you tried so far? It would help to not have to invent *all* of the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m <- as.matrix(read.table(text="0   15   20   17    0    0    4    5
0    7    0    8   20   18    0    1
0    0    5    8    0    5    7    0", header=F))

max_len_between_zeroes <- function(vec) {
  # vec : c(0, 15, 20, 17, 0, 0, 4, 5)
  vec2 <- cumsum(abs(diff(c(0,vec) != 0)))
  # vec2: c(0,  1,  1,  1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
  sums <- sapply(split(vec, vec2), sum)
  # sums:  0  1  2  3 
  #        0 52  0  9 
  sums[sums != 0]
  # returned:  1  3 
  #           52  9 
}

lapply(1:3, function(i) max_len_between_zeroes(m[i,]))
# [[1]]
#  1  3 
# 52  9 
# [[2]]
#  1  3  5 
#  7 46  1 
# [[3]]
#  1  3 
# 13 12
```

additional info after I have solved my problem
I found out that if I want to turn my list elements into matrix I have fallowed these codes. 
first run the function

```
na.zero <- function (x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- 0
  return(x)
}

matrix_of_list<-na.zero(matrix(sapply(1:length(mylist),function(j) mylist[[j]][1])))
```

Comment: that worked thanks, is there any way I can put these list numbers in a matrix ? I also have big data, that  I made this example to explanation the question   how I can figure it out with the big data do you know?

Comment: Given this example, how would you create a matrix where rows 1 and 3 have two elements, and row 2 has three elements? Matrices (in general as well as in R) need to be perfectly rectangular (in an *n*-dimensional sense).

Comment: if there is no element we can put zeros

Comment: But there are three elements in the second row. Or are you talking about padding everything so that they all are the same length? Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495520/3358272 can be of use.

Comment: The first question (*max length between zeroes*) has been answered. If you mean *"put these list numbers in a matrix"*, then the link I provided helps you to get there; once all of the vectors are the same length, you can use `do.call(rbind, list_returned_from_my_lapply_code))` to create a matrix.